# Hibernate and schema update when changing column type

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have Hibernate to set up my entities. For the developer environment I want Hibernate to handle schema updates (mostly some adding new columns, removing or editing column types). When adding a new column Hibernate will add it. Removing a field from the entity won't cause the column to drop from the database.  In some posts I've read that this is normal behaviour. But a problem was caused when I tried to edit the type of an entity field:

```
@Entity
class Person {

    String lastName; //This is the new column
}
```

This caused Hibernate to add a column of type VARCHAR(255) with default value of NULL and NOT NULL as YES.

The database already had one record (I am testing the behaviour) so Hibernate added the column with the existing behaviour with a value of empty string. I didn't add initialization of the column in the entity's constructor.

Changing the column type to `int` produced an error. Hibernate raised an `IllegalArgumentException` trying to add Null value to int field.

I thought Hibernate would drop the column, recreate it, and add Null value with no issue (since int fields can have NULL value). Is it good practice to always give a default value in a column name? Perhaps in a function with PrePersist?

```
@PrePersist
public void prePersist(){
    this.lastName = 5; //after changing lastName to int.
}
```

I want to add here that even in development we don't want to drop the table.  We want to keep current values.

Comment: In some cases it's not good to drop a table but you have to do it, in the development stage it's possible, or drop a schema to make sure the new schema to be generated upon restart.

Comment: My problem is why does it try to put null value when I say that my field is Not Null (this is the default behavour when not adding any annotations)

Comment: because your column is VARCHAR

Comment: but I change it in to int

Comment: It doesn't work until you drop a table and let hibernare to recover it.

Comment: aha...I see...So even If add a default value to string and change to a default value in int it would still produce an error right?

Comment: error is an adequate reaction of hibernate if the schema and model doesn't match.

Comment: You will run into problems with this very quickly. The biggest issue is when you rename a field in an Entity. For instance, if you decide to rename your `lastName` field to `familyName`, then Hibernate will create a new column for family name, but the old column will still be there. In other words, Hibernate does not know that it needs to rename the column.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the wrong tool. Hibernate schema migration where never assumed to be a full solution for schema migrations. You might find a solution for the current problem just to stumble on the next.

You should look into a real schema migration tool like [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) or [flyways](http://flywaydb.org/)

Comment: True and I know and you are correct. But because we are still on development phase and there might be a lot of migrations till product reaches a more final stage, I don't want to write (so the other members of the team) sql migration code for each and every change. Migration code for adding one column, thought something simple hibernate would be easy to handle

Comment: that flyway thing is awesome :D i though hibernate would do that, but now that i stuck and i didn't wanted to do .... things, i found it very useful

Comment: Flyway seems to have issues when migrating databases that have data in them.